# Trying to send data from Android Tablet to Android Wear device and losing

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I could really use some help.  I'm having trouble getting my Android Wear device to recognize data changes made by my activity that runs on my Android tablet. I'm relatively new to Android and very new to the Wear APIs so I might be missing something completely obvious or trivial without realizing. I've pieced together a project from a couple of examples from the Android Wear doc pages and from the TwoToasters example on github.  I just want to get data communication set up between the devices so that I can then edit the code in order to display images from my tablet on my Wear device.  Ultimately, I want to be able to start/stop a slideshow on my Wear device from my tablet but I should be able to get there on my own once I get the data communication protocol set up and working so I'm really just looking for help with that. Here is my code so far:

Mobile:

```
package com.example.administrator.moto360displaycontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Asset;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS = 100;
    private static final String ON_MESSAGE = "On!";
    private static final String OFF_MESSAGE = "Off!";
    private String message = null;
    int count = 0;

    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private String nodeId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initApi();
        setupWidgets();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the GoogleApiClient and gets the Node ID of the connected device.
     */
    private void initApi() {
        client = getGoogleApiClient(this);
        retrieveDeviceNode();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a GoogleApiClient that can access the Wear API.
     * @param context
     * @return A GoogleApiClient that can make calls to the Wear API
     */
    private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the GoogleApiClient and retrieves the connected device's Node ID. If there are
     * multiple connected devices, the first Node ID is returned.
     */
    private void retrieveDeviceNode() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result =
                        Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).await();
                List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                    nodeId = nodes.get(0).getId();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the button for handling click events.`
     */
    private void setupWidgets() {
        findViewById(R.id.toggleButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
                Asset asset = createAssetFromBitmap(bitmap);
                PutDataRequest request = PutDataRequest.create("/image");
                request.putAsset("profileImage", asset);
                Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(client, request);
                showToast("SentData");
            }
        });
    }

    private static Asset createAssetFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteStream);
        return Asset.createFromBytes(byteStream.toByteArray());
    }

    public void showToast(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Wear:

```
package com.example.administrator.moto360displaycontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Asset;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMapItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        DataApi.DataListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    private TextView mTextView;
    private static final long CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS = 100;
    private static final String ON_MESSAGE = "On!";
    private static final String OFF_MESSAGE = "Off!";
    private static final String TAG = "Moto360DisplayControl";
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private String nodeId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initApi();
    }

    private void initApi() {
        client = getGoogleApiClient(this);
        retrieveDeviceNode();
    }

    private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    }

    private void retrieveDeviceNode() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result =
                    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).await();
                List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                    nodeId = nodes.get(0).getId();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        client.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Wearable.DataApi.addListener(client, this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "AddedListener!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int num) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ConnectionSuspended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult res) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ConnectionFailed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(client, this);
        client.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "DataChanged!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
            if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED && event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals("/image")) {
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
                Asset profileAsset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("profileImage");
                Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromAsset(profileAsset);
                // Do something with bitmap
                Toast.makeText(this, "DataChanged!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap loadBitmapFromAsset(Asset asset) {
        if (asset == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Asset must be non-null");
        }

        ConnectionResult result = client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            return null;
        }

        // Convert asset into a file descriptor and block until it's ready
        InputStream assetInputStream = Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(client, asset).await().getInputStream();
        client.disconnect();

        if (assetInputStream == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Requested an unknown Asset.");
            return null;
        }

        // Decode the stream into a bitmap
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetInputStream);
    }
}
```

Everything "seems" to succeed as far as I can tell but the Toast in the Wear's "onDataChanged" method never shows up on the Wear's display which makes me think it isn't seeing the data change for some reason.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a timestamp to your request on the handheld, it did the trick for me back then, and I think Google updated their documentations adding this bit of info

Comment: I tried adding a time stamp with:

request.getDataMap().putLong("time", new Date().getTime());

but it did not help... I also looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676165/unable-to-push-data-to-android-wear-emulator question and re-arranged some code to look like what he has since he is essentially trying to do the same thing that I am but still no luck...this is driving me crazy

Comment: Do you have an actual wearabale device, or are you working with an emulator ? When I tried the Data API, I remember that I could not make it work with an emulator...

Comment: Sorry I left this open for so long! I've been crazy busy and forgot about it.  I actually found out that I wasn't properly embedding the wear application in the package, so when I installed an updated version of the mobile application it didn't update the wear application.  Once I figured this out it worked.  The timestamp IS important though!  It wouldn't have worked without the timestamp either.  Thanks for the replies, guys