# OnDataChanged is never called

Tags: android, wear-os, dataitem

I am trying the dataitem APi and here is my code

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                    Log.d("Inside", "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside On connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Now you can use the Data Layer API
                    //Creating Dataitem
                    PutDataMapRequest dataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create("/count");
                    dataMapRequest.setUrgent();
                    DataMap datamap=dataMapRequest.getDataMap();
                    PutDataRequest putDataRequest=dataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
                    datamap.putString("key", "Value");
                    PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult =
                            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataRequest);
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    Log.d("Inside", "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.d("Inside", "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                }
            })
            // Request access only to the Wearable API
            .addApiIfAvailable(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    Log.d("Inside","onDataChanged");
}
```

What am I missing out to trigger on data changed?. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141046/wearablelistenerservice-ondatachanged-is-not-called) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516177/ondatachanged-is-not-getting-called) but I am still unclear what am I supposed to change to enter on data changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using DataApi.DataListener, then you have to addListener after GoogleApiClient connected. Something like: `Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this)` inside your `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`.

If you are using WearableListenerService make sure you have similar code in your AndroidManifest.xml on the receiving/listening side as shown below:

```
<service android:name=".YourCustomWearableListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED"/>
            <data android:scheme="wear" 
                  android:host="*" 
                  <!-- I believe pathPrefix is optional, removing it will make the service listener to all data change events -->
                  android:pathPrefix="/YourDataMapPathPrefix"/>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also keep in mind that `onDataChanged` will get call only if the data is ACTUALLY changed. Let's said that the old data is ("Person", "Bob") and you replace it with same data ("Person", "Bob"), then `onDataChanged` will not get triggered since the data does not change in fact. But `onDataChanged` will get triggered if you put ("Person", "Bob2") instead.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me! I dont know how I missed it.