# onDataChanged isn´t called on android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, dataitem

I want to send just simple Strings from Smartphone to android wear. I looked in this Question before: [Unable to push data to android wear (Emulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676165/unable-to-push-data-to-android-wear-emulator)
and tried to do the same way, but onDataChanged only when i delete the hole App on my Phone, but not when push StringstoWear is called.
Hope for Help...

Here is my Code on Phone:
    package de.gruppe8.culturehelper;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.util.Date;

public class Phone extends AppCompatActivity implements          GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener     {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String TAG = "PHONE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone);

    //Erstelle Google API Client zur Kommunikation mit Wear
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    //Testbutton zum Daten versenden
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Testbutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pushStringsToWear();
        }
    });

}

//Sendet Daten an Wear, wenn aufgerufen  !!!!--->Auchtung wird noch nicht         richtig empfangen
private void pushStringsToWear() {

    Inhalt.TEXT ="ätzend";
    //Requester
    PutDataMapRequest Sender =     PutDataMapRequest.create(Inhalt.NOTIFICATION_PATH);

       //Diese Daten werden versendet, unter dem angegeben Pfad (siehe hier drüber)
    Sender.getDataMap().putLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Sender.getDataMap().putString("Bilddateiname", Inhalt.IMAGE);
    Sender.getDataMap().putString("Text", Inhalt.TEXT);


    Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient,     Sender.asPutDataRequest());

    //bestätigt das aufrufen der Funktion
    TextView Information = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Information);
    String a= "dgdfjkjhg";
    Information.setText(a);
}

//zu versendende Daten--->müssen anhand der Datenbank vor dem Absenden     verändert werden
public static class Inhalt {

    public static  String NOTIFICATION_PATH = "/Warning";
    public static  Long Zeit = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public static  String IMAGE = "Image";
    public static String TEXT = "content";


}

//Pflichtfunktionen onStart,onStop,onConnected,onConnectionFailed/Suspended,     onStop
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.d(TAG, "connected to APICLIENT" + new Date().getTime());
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Failed");
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "disconected from APICLIENT" + new Date().getTime());
}



}
```

And this is my code on Wear:

```
package de.gruppe8.culturehelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMapItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Watch extends Activity implements      GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,   DataApi.DataListener, MessageApi.MessageListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String TAG = "WEAR";

private TextView mTextView;
GoogleApiAvailability a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch);

    //Starten des Google API Clients zur kommunikation mit Smartphone

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

//Wenn Daten vom Handy abgesendet werden, werden sie hier empfangen ---> Derzeit nur bei Deinstallation der App
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvent) {
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvent) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED &&
                event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals("/Warning")) {


            final DataMapItem dMI = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
            //Empfangbare Daten, zur weiterverarbeitung If states einbauen und Folge festlegen(externe Funktionen?)
            String Text = dMI.getDataMap().getString("Text");
            String Bild = dMI.getDataMap().getString("Bilddateiname");
            Long Zeit = dMI.getDataMap().getLong("time");

            //Teststring
                TextView Testergebnis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            String s= Objects.toString(Zeit, null);
                Testergebnis.setText(s);
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
//Startet die Listener
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (null != mGoogleApiClient && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Failed");
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

}
}
```

wear Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.gruppe8.culturehelper">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <activity
        android:name=".Watch"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:allowEmbedded="true"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to     your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more   information. -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

Phone Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Phone">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to  your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with [Play Services 8.3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/11/whats-new-in-google-play-services-83.html), data synchronization using DataApi is batched up and done with a certain frequency which means synchronization of your data can be delayed up to 30 minutes. If you need immediate sync, you need to make sure your request is set as [urgent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/PutDataMapRequest.html#setUrgent()). As a side note, it is a good practice to check for the connectivity of the ApiClient when you are using it, for example in your `pushStringsToWear`